# Blender script: add ALL OBJECT to command?

Tags: scripting

I have got very simple script :

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

bpy.context.object.show_wire = True

bpy.data.objects["Lamp"].show_wire = True

bpy.data.objects["Camera"].show_wire = True

bpy.data.objects["Suzanne.001"].show_wire = True
```

What i need is that ["Suzanne.001"] will not be specified but rather be something universal for ALL objects in scene, is there something similar like ["all_objects"] or something like that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `show_wire` to be `True` for all objects, not just "Suzanne.001"?

If so, all you need to do is iterate over the objects in the scene with a [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop):

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    obj.show_wire = True
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well thank for input, but if I use this let's say in this example :

Comment: `import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    obj.show_wire = True`

Comment: It still doesn't show wire on all objects but one. JESUS this text editor is nightmare :D

Comment: I'm struggling to repeat your problem, it may help if you upload the blend file you are using.

Comment: Also, it's possible that it **is** showing wire on all objects, but it may seem like it's only showing wire on one object (the selected object). The wire will appear black on unselected objects. Have you checked that all the objects in the scene to see if "Wire" is checked in the display settings?

Comment: Also, you don't need `bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')` in your code

Comment: Hmm, I will try to add screen to demonstrate my problem. It might be worth noting that I am using Blender 2.8.

Comment: I attached screen to OP where you can see that I tried your code but still wire appears only on that one object (on screen i clicked on different object so you can see it is not just graphic thing but wire frame is not ticked there).

Comment: This is why it is pointless to ask or answer questions about 2.8. The latest build works fine. Whatever you are using is not today's build. 2.8 is not finished yet. If you want to experiment with it, please do, but right now the way I see it you are just wasting time of the kind people who are trying to help you. That's not a very nice thing to do.

Comment: Ok in 2.79 it is indeed working thank you mr. Bollans for solution! Martin Z I am sorry that you see it this way but it really wasn't my intention. I was trying to find it out myself but since i am really newbie in terms of coding I needed help. Yes 2.8 was a problem and I didn't realize that and I will be more careful about that in future, but I don't think I deserve to be accused like that.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working!